# JQuery в Internet Explorer 7: баг позиции элемента в конце анимации через .animate()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, explorer

После анимации очередной элемент смещается на определённую высоту и в конце концов уходит из области просмотра. Код примера на http://www.2780780.ru/workaround/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предположить, что текст, который находится внутри li приводит к такому эффекту - height:0 и overflow:hidden не помогают полностью спрятать элемент, попробуйте прятать их в display:none после отработки.

**UPD:** Добавил это в цсс и работает в ие6+, сам скрипт можно не менять

```
li
{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url("images/bg-sample.png");
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

li div
{
    color: #6B5E34;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: url("images/bug.png") no-repeat 8px center;
}
```

Comment: Вариант решения добавлен в пример, в конце наблюдается резкий скачок

Comment: Да, {float: left; width: 100%} для li помог решить проблему, благодарю.